# Formatting Elements After an Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to have an ajax call apply formatting to elements that won't exist until its complete.  Using a success function in the actual call isn't working.  The function is called properly but the element ('.content-cell') isn't found, presumably because it doesn't exist yet.  The majority of similar answers address event delegation but not applying styles.

Am I approaching this correctly?  What is the best method for applying styling and handlers after an ajax retrieval?

```
$("#calendar-panel").load("url", setupCal());


function setupCal(){
    console.log("setupCal");
    var cell_width = $('.weekday-cell').width();
    if ($('.content-cell').length){
        console.log("Content cell exists");
    } else {
        console.log("Content cell does not exist");
    }
    $('.content-cell').css({height:cell_width});
```

The console output of this code is: 'setupCal'; 'Content cell does not exist'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you are actually calling the `setupCal` function in the line that is executing the `load` function. This would be because you have included the parentheses which would actually execute the function (and return it's results) as opposed to passing it as the callback argument.

You can try just referencing the name of the function in that line like so:

```
$("#calendar-panel").load("url", setupCal);
```

If the `setupCal` function is called while the `load` function is being 'defined' then the element will certainly not exist yet and hence give you the output you are seeing: ""Content cell does not exist"".

Comment: Upvoted, thanks.  This does seem to be the problem.  However, I have a later function that needs to be called with specific arguments and I'm not sure how that would work.  Additionally, the official jquery docs show a function being called in-line with the load.  What's up with that.

Comment: The docs show a function definition, yes.. But it's not 'manually' being executed with parentheses. An inline callback (as shown in the docs) would be good for triggering a call to a different function and would allow you to pass arguments in a more readable and flexible manner. You just make the call to your separate function from within the callback.